# FetchType.EAGER why has shorter latency then FetchMode.JOIN

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

Why when I use `FetchMode.JOIN` I get longer latency than `FetchType.EAGER` ?

I should add than, there is real small collection.

1.With join:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set<Property> properties;
```

2.With Eager:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<Property> properties;
```

I thought that solution with join is more performence then Eager. Maybe small size of collection is the reason ?

Comment: You **can't say for sure** which case is better in terms of performance because the answer depends on the context. 

You should consider the following items:

 - what are the other relations for this entity 
 - which fetch strategy do you use for the other relations
 - what are the size of the database tables

Comment: Thank you, i understend it depends :)